# Rewriting a union of cartesian products

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am wondering if the following is a proper way to rewrite the union of cartesian products.

Let $A$ be the following set:
\begin{equation*}
    A=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{ 0\}} \left(\{q\} \times \left[0,\frac{1}{d_q}\right]\right).
\end{equation*}
Where $d_q > 0$. Is the following the same as $A$?
\begin{align*}
    A &= \underbrace{\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{ 0\}} \left(\{q\} \times \left(0,\frac{1}{d_q}\right]\right)}_{A_1} \cup 
\underbrace{\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{ 0\}} \big(\{q\} \times \{0\}\big)}_{\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\} \times \{0\}}\\
&= A_1 \cup \big(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\} \times \{0\}\big).
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So, does than mean the closure of $A$ is just the closure of $A_1$ union the closure of $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\} \times \{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, it does: it’s true in general that $\operatorname{cl}(A\cup B)=(\operatorname{cl}A)\cup\operatorname{cl}B$. In this case it’s even true that $\operatorname{cl}A=\operatorname{cl}A_1$, since $\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}\times\{0\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! I have to computer this closure in the Moore Plane Topology $\Gamma$, however, it seems the answer I am getting is different than the one I am being told...do you, by any chance, happen to know what the closure of $A$ would be in $\Gamma$?

Comment: That will depend a great deal on the numbers $d_q$.

Comment: Ah, in the problem it says that $q = \frac{n_q}{d_q}$ ($q \in \mathbb{Q}$) where $n_q,d_q \in \mathbb{Z}$ are relatively prime, and $d_q > 0$.

Comment: If $x\in\{0\}\cup(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)$ and $y>0$, $\langle x,y\rangle\notin\operatorname{cl}A$: it takes a little work to verify it, but you can choose $\epsilon<\frac{y}2$ small enough so that if $x-\epsilon<q<x+\epsilon$, $\frac1{d_q}<\frac{y}2$. Thus, you only have to worry about points $\langle x,0\rangle$ with irrational $x$ or $x=0$, and I’ll have to think a little about those.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, this was the approach taken, actually. However, I was trying to take a different approach, that is, split $A$ up as I did, then compute the closure of each set. I know that any subset of the $x$-axis is closed in the Moore Plane Topology, so I figured $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\times\{0\}$ is closed, right? Hence its closure would be itself? Then I would only need to compute the closure of $A_1$...

Comment: And it’s actually not hard to see that the origin is in the closure of $A$. The irrationals are a little trickier, but the same goes for them.

Comment: It’s true that you need only compute $\operatorname{cl}A_1$, but that doesn’t materially change the work that you have to do: it’ll be essentially the same argument.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, thanks for the help! The final answer did claim that the whole $x$-axis was in the closure of $A$.

Comment: You’re welcome! Yes, that’s the same result that I get.

Comment: Just to confirm...did you get $\operatorname{cl}(A) = A \cup X$, where $X$ is the $x$-axis?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.